# Blazor EditForm with hidden field

Tags: c#, blazor

I created a simple form to edit data in new release of Blazor with .Net 8.0. Is a very simple form defined in this way:

```
<EditForm Model="Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="Save" FormName="Edit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <hr />
    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.A" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="A" />
        <label for="nome">A</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.A" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

`Input` is my `ConfigurationDTO` model that have some fields. The problem is on field `Id` that I lost in my `Save` event. This field isn't in my `EditForm` and I didn't found a way to bind it. I tried whit simple hidden field but doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" @bind-value="Input.Id" />
```

What's the correct way to preserve my `Id` field?

**UPDATE 29/11/2023**

I found a solution to the issue. To bind data I use an input type hidden with name in this form: `Input.Id`. The simple name `Id` doesn't work. My opinion is that this is a workaround, so I opened an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52347

Comment: On the assumption this is a Blazor form in a component, why are you trying to "post" it?  `Save` has access to the `Input` property which is the edited object, and thus contains the Id.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I use this video as a guide: https://youtu.be/YwZdtLEtROA?t=1182. However, the problem is in the new version of Blazor .Net 8.0. I tried my code in Blazor .Net 6.0 and it works fine. Probably they has changed something behind the scene. Your suggest is to work without `post` and `OnValidSubmit` and pass `Input` as a parameter to `Save` method when I click on the button? In this way I'll lost validation. However, I already try to remove `post` preserving `OnValidSubmit` but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score -3):

In Blazor, if you have a field that you want to include in your form but don't want to display it or edit it directly, you can use the `InputHidden` component. This component allows you to include a hidden input field in your form and bind it to a model property. Here's how you can modify your code to include a hidden field for the Id property:

```
<EditForm Model="Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="Save" FormName="Edit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <hr />
    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />

    <!-- Hidden field for Id -->
    <InputHidden @bind-Value="Input.Id" />

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.A" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="A" />
        <label for="nome">A</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.A" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't any `InputHidden` component

Comment: ok, then try a different approach using the Bind attribute directly on the hidden field: `<input type="hidden" @bind="Input.Id" />`

Comment: Same issue. I can't find anything on web