# Blazor interactive mode WebAssembly serialization issue

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I tried to create a simple component with Blazor. The component is a custom checkbox.

```
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<span class="check" @onclick="ToggleCheck">
    @if (Value) {
        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
    }
</span>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    protected void ToggleCheck()
    {
        Value = !Value;
    }
}
```

In this way everything works fine, but now I need to add this piece of code:

```
[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<bool>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
```

I need it to get property name of passed value and use it to create an input hidden where store bool value. This because, whit Blazor 8, change a model property has no effect on it if there isn't input field where to store it (relative to my other question: [Blazor EditForm with hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77529823/blazor-editform-with-hidden-field)).
When I added this part I obtain this error in browser:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances is not supported. Path: $.Type.
```

What could cause it?