# Blazor 8.0 two-way-binding

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm starting to think there is something wrong with new Blazor 8.0. Today I created a new Input component to handle decimal values. This is the code:

```
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<input type="text" @bind="Value" name="@NameAttributeValue" 
    @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" 
    @onkeydown="@OnKeydown" 
    @onkeydown:preventDefault="@PreventDefault"
    @oninput="@OnInput" />

@code {
    protected bool PreventDefault = false;

    private Regex _inputRule = new Regex(@$"[0-9{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}]");
    private List<string> _allowedCodes = new List<string> {
        KeyCodes.ArrowDown,
        KeyCodes.ArrowLeft,
        KeyCodes.ArrowRight,
        KeyCodes.ArrowUp,
        KeyCodes.Backspace,
        KeyCodes.Delete
    };

    private Regex _decimalRule = new Regex(@$"^[0-9]+{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}?[0-9]+$");

    private string _lastChar = "";

    [Parameter]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string NameAttributeValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected void OnKeydown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_allowedCodes.Contains(e.Code)) {
            PreventDefault = _inputRule.Replace(e.Key, "") != "";

            if (!PreventDefault) {
                PreventDefault = e.Key == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator && Value.ToString().Contains(',');
            }
        }
        else {
            PreventDefault = false;
        }
    }

    protected void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_decimalRule.IsMatch(e.Value.ToString())) {
            Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is class `KeyCodes`:

```
public class KeyCodes {
    public const string Backspace = "Backspace";
    public const string ArrowLeft = "ArrowLeft";
    public const string ArrowUp = "ArrowUp";
    public const string ArrowRight = "ArrowRight";
    public const string ArrowDown = "ArrowDown";
    public const string Delete = "Delete";
}
```

And in my page I use component in this way:

```
<InputDecimal @bind-Value="Total" name="Total" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="Total" />
```

The problem is that `Value` is always `0`. It never changes but in textbox I can see correct value. Am I doing something wrong?
In this case I don't try this code on older version of Blazor, but I guess it works for them.

Comment: @bind-value="@Total" ...

Comment: @GHDevOps value must have uppercase V

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

Here's a working template using your code.  I've taken the liberty of refactoring the code to use the built in Blazor Input functionality to check decimal conversion.

```cs
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@using System.Globalization

<input type="@_inputType"
       value="@_currentValueAsString"
       @onchange="this.OnValueChanged"
       @oninput="this.OnValueInput"
       @attributes="this.AdditionalAttributes" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public decimal Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public Dictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? NameAttributeValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool UpdateOnInput { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool AsNumber { get; set; }

    private CultureInfo _currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    private decimal _currentValue;
    private string _inputType => AsNumber ? "number" : "text";
    private string _currentValueAsString => BindConverter.FormatValue(this.Value, _currentCulture);

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        _currentValue = this.Value;

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the value and callback if we're updating on the Change Event 
        if (!this.UpdateOnInput)
            await UpdateValue(e);
    }

    protected async Task OnValueInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the value and callback if we're updating on the Input Event
        if (this.UpdateOnInput)
            await UpdateValue(e);
    }

    protected async Task UpdateValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentValueAsString = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

        // Use built in component functionality to check the input string
        if (!BindConverter.TryConvertToDecimal(currentValueAsString, _currentCulture, out _currentValue))
            _currentValue = 0;

        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_currentValue);
    }
}
```

Home:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2 p-2 bg-light">
    <label>As Text with Update on Exit (try typing 1,000)</label>
    <InputDecimal @bind-Value="_value1" class="form-control mb-3" aria-required="true" placeholder="Total" />

    <label>As Text with Update on input</label>
    <InputDecimal UpdateOnInput @bind-Value="_value2" class="form-control mb-3" aria-required="true" placeholder="Total" />

     <label>As Number with Update on Exit</label>
     <InputDecimal UpdateOnInput AsNumber @bind-Value="_value3" class="form-control mb-3" aria-required="true" placeholder="Total" />
 </div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value: @_value1</pre>
    <pre>Value: @_value2</pre>
    <pre>Value: @_value3</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private decimal _value1;
    private decimal _value2;
    private decimal _value3;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Logic is to prevent user to insert invalid characters. Anyway, this solution doesn't works. `Value` is always 0 and now, when I focus out input, text come back to 0.

Comment: See my revised answer.  It contains the code I showed you originally.

Comment: I can't see any important differences. I tried to change `text` to `number` but it doesn't works. Same behaviour. I think is the same problem i faced off in this other questionthat I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77529823/blazor-editform-with-hidden-field. With Blazor 7.0 I have no issues with same code of question. No data lost on submit. Maybe same problem here...

Comment: The major difference between your code and mine is in the bind.  You do ` @bind="Value"` which won't work.  Can you do a  [MRE] that you can post to Github?  If I put your code in a demo page I can't resolve `KeyCodes`.  Is that your own enum?

Comment: I don't now how to create an example online. KeyCodes is a simple class with some constant strings. I'll edit my answer with class. I already change my code with `@bind:get` and `@bind:set` without success.

Comment: Your code is now a [MRE].  I've updating my answer to demonstrate how you can use some built in Bind functionality to do the heavy lifting for you.  I think it does what you want i.e. deal with culture.

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior remains the same and the data is not updated. What version of .Net did you create the example with? My solution contains two projects: `MyProject` and `MyProject.Client`. In the `Client` part I placed the component, which requires the `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` instruction to work.

Comment: Net8. You should not be setting interactivity on components like this.  They should work in either Blazor Server or WebAssembly.  Interactivity should be set at the page or global level.  Here's a Repo with both Server and WASM global projects.   Change the startup project . https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO77920963.

Comment: On thinking about this I'm going to guess that you have no Interactivity set.  What `@rendermode` do you have set on `Routes` in `App` and on the page where you have this component?  If you're migrating from 7 or lower you should set global interactivity in `App`.

Comment: I didn't migrate from a project in .net 7 to this one. I created a new project with Blazor 8.0 leaving all settings default, except for `@renderemode` in component. But also `EditForm` and standard components works completely different compared to version 7.0.

Comment: It depends on where you set interactivity.   Choose Interactivity as *Global* in either Server or WebAssembly and it's the same as Net7-.  Don't go for broke and choose *Per Page/Component*.  It's a minefield unless you really know what you're doing.  -  see https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.Interactivity and https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering

Comment: You need to look closely at the projects in the Repo I've pointed you to.  Look closely at the setup of  *App.razor* and the pages. Figure out what you're doing differently.

Comment: In `App.razor` there's nothing interesting about it. `Routes.razor` has no references to `rendermode`. In `Program.cs` there is this setting: `builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents().AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();`.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting, I
skipped the value conversion part to focus on the core issue, as it seems there's a misunderstanding about the binding.

In Blazor, parent components handle data and state management, passing data to child components via Parameters.

Unlike traditional .NET developments like WinForms or WPF, where controls may manage their own data, Blazor's approach simplifies data consistency and state management by promoting unidirectional data flow.

Data moves from parents to children, with children using but not modifying it. Modifications are communicated through events to parents, enhancing application maintainability and debuggability.

Therefore, child components must 'notify' their parent components when a value changes.
Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-with-component-parameters

You need to declare

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

and call

```
ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
```

to notify about the value change.

@bind-XXX="value" is simply syntactic sugar that simplifies writing

```
XXX="value"
XXXChanged="v => value = v"
```

Comment: What you say it's correct. I already worked with previous version of Blazor. Now I'm focused on component. It just doesn't do what is requested in the OnInput method. Also, calling `ValueChanged` method doesn't work. I have some issues with bindings in this new version of Blazor. Everything seems different.

Comment: @erikscandola 
I haven't encountered any issues while developing with the new Blazor WebApp (.Net 8).

First, try testing your component with the default Blazor WebApp Template (Interactive server mode).

If it works fine there, the problem might not be with the binding, but something else.

Comment: @erikscandola Additionally, if it turns out to be another issue, it might be better to provide not only the source of that specific component but also the entire project source.

Comment: simply try creating a form using a template with an initialized Id and a string field. In the form just put an `InputText` for the string. When the form is submitted the id will be lost. In Blazor 7.0 it was preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from your comment to my other answer:

> In App.razor there's nothing interesting about it. Routes.razor has no references to rendermode. In Program.cs there is this setting: builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents().AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

This along with other comments indicates you chose [intentionally or by accident] the "I Want it All" options when you created your solution.  Mode: *Auto* and Interactivity: *Per Page/Component*

This means:

1. There's no Global interactivity set in your application.
2. You almost certainly have no interactivity set in your demo page using `InputDecimal`.

To counter this you believe you need to set interactivity on the component.  Wrong.  Such components should be render mode agnostic.

In general you should be setting the Render mode Globally.  *Auto* and *Per Page/Component* is a minefield you need to be an expert to navigate.

I strongly recommend setting global interactivity.  You're App should look like this:

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WASM.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveWebAssembly" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveWebAssembly" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can then forget about setting it down the component tree.

Comment: [Polite] If you choose to ignore this advice, you're flying solo. Bon Voyage, I'm signing out.

Comment: I removed `rendermode` in my component and set in `Routes` as you show me. But the behaviour is the same. No two-way-binding. My project was created following this demo: https://youtu.be/YwZdtLEtROA?feature=shared&t=2124. No idea what's wrong with my project. Thank you for your time.

Comment: "But the behaviour is the same. No two-way-binding. "  Your original component was broken: it won't ever work.  Have you updated it?  Does my component work in your setup?  No one can help you if you don't show your revised component.

Comment: I create a new empty project using you're code for component, setting `rendermode` on `Routes` but nothing works. I tried to remove my custom component and use only one `InputText` with your black box where to show value but it remais an empty string.

Comment: With `@rendermode=@InteractiveWebAssembly` in `Routes` also default `Counter` example stop working.

Comment: Publish your demo project to Github.  What are you doing that's so different to https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO77920963.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try to publish on Github. I'm unable to configure multiple SSH connections with differents accounts. Anyway, why did you move Layout, Routes and Pages to Client project? This is the biggest difference. I think i can't do that.

Comment: That's the way the template deploys a *InteractiveWebAssembly*  and *Global* solution.  All the `InteractiveWebAssembly` pages have to be in the Client project.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I had to troubleshoot other projects. At the moment it seems that from my PC I cannot configure multiple connections to different Bitbucket accounts. In any case, I cannot follow the approach of your example. I need only the components to be in the client side. However, I repeat, several functions have changed compared to version 7, in my opinion for the worse.